# Unable to push all expected data to an array from collection using foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to add data to an array `$result` where each value is a string `$idstring` which will contain the employees ids like `"999|888|777"`. The data is fetched from `broadcastTbl` collection from a MongoDB. I need to fetch each employee's corresponding details in a loop and push to `$result`. I am successfully fetching the data, but the trouble I am facing is in the below code where only one employees' data is getting pushed to the `$result` array.

```
$projection =  array("broadcast_id" => 1, "employeeList" => 1);
$query = array("broadcast_id" => $broadcast_id);
$count = $this->collection->find($query)->count();
$cursor = $this->collection->find($query, $projection);

$result = array();
foreach($cursor as $row)
{
    $idstring = trim($row["employeeList"]);
    $idstring = preg_replace('/\.$/', '', $idstring);
    $idarray = explode('|', $idstring); 

    foreach($idarray as $employeeId) 
    {   
        $this->EmployeeCollection = $this->db->EmployeesTbl;
        $EmployeeCursor= $this->EmployeeCollection->find(array("EmployeeNumber" => $employeeId));
        $EmployeeCursorCount= $this->EmployeeCollection->find(array("EmployeeNumber" => $employeeId))->count();

        if($EmployeeCursor->count() > 0)
        {
            array_push($result,$EmployeeCursorCount);
            foreach ($EmployeeCursor as $k => $row) {
                array_push($result, $row);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($result, array("datanotfound"=>1));
        }

        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning too early.

Move `return json_encode($result);`

After the outer-most `foreach` loop.

Comment: Also please check why $EmployeeCursorCount is always one... please help

Comment: My guess is that `EmployeeNumber` is a unique value in your `EmployeesTbl` and the count would only ever be `1`. You should check your table rows though. Otherwise, if there is still another issue you should ask another question (if you can't figure it out after attempting a few things).